# Error 404 for JQuery import "jquery-1.10.2.min.map"

Tags: themes

I got my WordPress 3.6 installation running using a theme I have bought. When I'm using my theme the console says:

```
GET ...xyz.de/landing/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.map 404 (Not Found)
```

This error does not appear when using the default theme. This seems like a broken import of a jQuery file. The site seems to work with the theme enabled. Where should I start looking to fix this in a theme not written by me?

Best regards,

Chris

Comment: It should be enqueued in `wp-content/YOUR-THEME/functions.php`

Comment: but i guess that it's not the problem

Comment: please can you show us the list of js script loaded by your site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue for WordPress 3.6. There is already a [ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24994) in the WordPress bug tracker. A patch can be found [there](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/24994/24994.patch) too but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: The issue has been resolved in WordPress version 3.6.1 using this patch http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/24994/24994.patch

Answer (score 0):

WordPress ships with a minified version of jQuery that includes a `sourceMappingURL` directive which browsers (currently only Chrome I think) can use to grab a ["source map"](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) that maps out how the minified code maps to the regular version.

However, WordPress does not include the .map file itself.

Nothing is broken with your jQuery import, and that error should only show up when you open up Developer Tools/Web Inspector.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts dave! The error only appears for my custom theme. Is this still a non critical error?

Comment: I would imaging the other themes you're looking at aren't loading jQuery, or they load jQuery from someplace like Google which is a whole different set of problems.

Trac [ticket 24994](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24994) for WordPress core addresses this error by removing the source map declaration from the jquery.js that comes with WordPress.

[Ticket 24879](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24879) is where the core developers are talking about how to incorporate the jQuery source map into WordPress even though they're using a customized version of jQuery.